# NuGet dependencies and multiple DLL versions

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, nuget

I'm currently developing an Umbraco website using ASP.NET MVC. The website also has a reference to another component which uses EntityFramework 5 to connect to a different database than the CMS's one. (Both databases are MySQL).

I'm using NuGet to manage my dependencies. These are (among others) the current packages I have and their dependencies:

DataComponent

```
   -> MySQL.Data.Entities 6.7.4
      -> MySql.Data 6.7.4 (dependency for at least 6.7.4)
```

Web

```
Umbraco core
    -> MySql.Data 6.6.5 (exact version)
```

The problem is now that the web component has a reference to the data component and thus the references to MySQL.Data conflict:

- I cannot update MySql.Data in the web component, because Umbraco core has a dependency on that specific version
- I cannot downgrade the datacomponent package because there's an error with the 6.6.5 version of the MySQL.Data.Entities component.

What I tried to do was some some bindingRedirects to a folder outside of the bin:

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.6.5.0" newVersion="6.6.5.0" />
   <codeBase version="6.7.4.0" href="Assembly/6.7.4/MySql.Data.dll"/>
   <codeBase version="6.6.5.0" href="Assembly/6.6.5/MySql.Data.dll"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

The problem here is that the AssemblyBinder looks inside the bin-directory first, and there's the 6.6.5-version of the DLL, hence it's manifest definition doesn't match the assembly. It's in the bin-folder because I still want the package as a NuGet package.

The only thing I can think of is to completely remove the Umbraco-package and resolve it manually. That way there wouldn't be a DLL in the bin and the AssemblyBinder would have to look in the correct folder. I don't want to do this because I need the package to be setup correctly in our CI server and on other developer PC's. Also, the package has many other dependencies that I would like to have resolved automatically.

Does anyone know of a different solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to test this but have had similar issues. In those cases I wrote something like this

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.6.5.0" newVersion="6.6.5.0" />
   <codeBase version="6.6.5.0" href="bin\Assembly\6.6.5\MySql.Data.dll"/>
   <codeBase version="6.7.4.0" href="bin\MySql.Data.dll"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Biggest difference from your file is that I have the default mysql in the bin folder since it's picked up with reflection.